# My gridlayout is not inflating as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.package.name.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="4">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout file. I was expecting a 4x4 grid with the accent color in column 1, row 2 and the primary color in column 3, row 2, the rest blank. But instead I just get the whole gridlayout filled with the accent color, there isn't even a cell with the primary color. Why is this? How do I achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your first `ImageView` has a width and height of `match_parent`, so it is filling the entire layout with itself. You can see something like you want to see by just defining a width and height to each `ImageView`, say `100dp`. That's not what you want, but it can get you started. Also, take a look at "Excess Space Distribution" at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html.

Comment: Ok, interesting. So when I set the height and width to `100dp` I do get 2 separate boxes, each `100dp x 100dp` but they are not in the cells that I want. They are at the top left and top right corners of the screen even though I've defined the `layout_column` and `layout_row` for each. I'm looking at the documentation for this, but it's not really clear to me. I thought I'd just be able to treat this like a grid?

Comment: @intA I think that you will need to define each cell. You are right, there is not a lot of documentation or examples of this `ViewGroup` online.

Comment: @intA Have you seen [this tutorial](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/gridlayout-part-1/)? It goes into some depth about how the layout works.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. Though I just found the TableLayout and that might be easier to use for my case. Either that or a LinearLayout containing 4 horizontal LinearLayouts within it.

Comment: @intA `TableLayout` is very intuitive. You might also consider chains in `ConstraintLayout` for a flatter layout structure.